# Tidyverse extract elemens from character conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to locate in this dataframe the elements of var1 for which the elements of var2 are different

> data.frame(var1=c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c"),
> var2=c("X","X","X","Y","Z","W","W","W"),
> stringsAsFactors = F)

expected result

> data.frame(var1=c("b"))

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(var1) %>% filter(length(unique(var2))>1) %>% distinct(var1)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
# Groups:   var1 [1]
  var1 
  <chr>
1 b
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @Karthik S another alternative approach and if i understood correctly the question.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(var1=c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c"), var2=c("X","X","X","Y","Z","W","W","W"), stringsAsFactors = F)


dplyr::select(
   distinct(df)[duplicated(distinct(df)$var1),], var1
   )
```

Call select only if you need to guarantee that the output is a dataframe/tibble.